# performance counter

Tags: c++, windows

Here is the code, to get the bandwidth of the system from the system, using counter .
I'm getting "PdhCollectQueryData failed"

ie.error code = "PDH_NO_DATA"
plz tell me where i'm going wrong.?????

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pdh.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"pdh.lib")
```

Comment: When you debug it, does it run through once ok?  ie is the failure happening the first time PdhCollectQueryData is called?

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't you include the output from those Enum calls, which presumably worked for you since they are not commented out?

I'd be surprised if there is a space in `COUNTER_PATH` after the second opening parenthesis, as you have here.  I'd expect the name to not have a leading space.

```
CONST LPCSTR COUNTER_PATH = TEXT("\\Network Interface( NVIDIA nForce Networking Controller - PacketScheduler Miniport)\\Current Bandwidth");
```